# hover is acting as a click in small size views

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

when I go to different views like 1024 X 768 then hover is acting as click. Buts its working fine in normal laptop size window.

when I hover over link it changes color to blue, but in small size screen it doesn't change color on hover, it change color on click

Below is HTML code

```
<div class="account-wrapper">
<ul>
<li>{{...}}
<span   class="helpIcon icon-interface-question-mark" (click)="toggleHsaInfo()"> 
</span>
</li>
</ul>
<div>
```

Below is scss code

```
.account-wrapper {
  border-bottom: 1px solid $border-color;
  .icon-interface-question-mark {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;

    &:hover {
      color:blue;
    }
  }
```

I tried to solve like this

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 768px) 
and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
{

.account-wrapper{
  .icon-interface-question-mark{
    &:hover {
      color: blue;
    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Please share your HTML code

Comment: please check it now

Comment: What do you mean "hover is acting as click"? What do you want your code to do?

Comment: when I hover over link it changes color to blue, but in small size screen it doesn't change color on hover, it change color on click

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is related to mobile devices without the ability to hover. You can accomplish this in various ways but I prefer CSS media queries.

```
.account-wrapper {
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  .icon-interface-question-mark {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

@media (hover: hover) {
    .helpIcon:hover { color: blue; }
}


@media(hover:none){
    *:hover { color: inherit !important; }
    *:active {color: blue !important;}
}
```

You can also try `@media(hover:on-demand)`

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ou67ut?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss

Comment: Thanks, but we want ontouch color blue only

Comment: I updated the answer, I'm still not positive what you want on mobile devices.

Comment: I guess on mobile devices active is not working, my issue is, in mobile if I touch the link it should be blue, later If I am not touching it, it should be not blue in color. i.e it should be blue only if I am touching the link

Comment: https://codepen.io/SahilKatia/pen/GBGEXa

on above link, can you fade border box if user is not touching it (once user touched it)